# A potentially trans student is misgendered in university records. What should I do?

Tags: teaching, university, europe, gender

I have noticed* that an undergrad student in a course I teach has "female" written in the "gender" field in the university intranet database (used for course enrollment, grading, etc.), although they present themselves as male in terms of appearance and pronouns.

I would have chalked it up to a simple clerical error, but then I realized that the student's name also is of a somewhat unisex character (it's common for men but not entirely rare for women as well, think "Andy"), so there is a small but nonzero probability the student is actually trans.

Of course I could just ignore the issue completely, but that would mean the wrong gender would keep being shown to dozens of other teachers for years to come, and that might put the student into all kinds of uncomfortable situations.

I'm thus trying to balance the invasion of the student's privacy by bringing this up in some way vs the invasion of their privacy caused by the problematic gender field in the database.

I was thinking about sending them a short e-mail along the lines of:

> Dear Student, I have noticed the university records show your gender as female. Should you want to have that corrected, contact the Department of Student Affairs. Feel free to ignore this message if it is not relevant, I don't expect a reply.

Is there a better (read: more respectful, safer, less likely to come across as super creepy) course of action?

*: Noticing this didn't require any investigation whatsoever. When I open the teacher dashboard for my course,I am presented with a list of students. One entry in that list looks like

> Andy Smith (F) (photo of a bearded dude)

That's not really easy to miss in a list with less than 30 rows.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134597/discussion-on-question-by-tootea-potentially-trans-student-misgendered-in-univer). Please read [this FAQ](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4230) before posting another comment.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

If you [must do something](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Politician%27s_syllogism) (an assumption I would encourage you to question), then probably the best way to help the student avoid uncomfortable situations, without actually putting them in exactly the kind of uncomfortable situation you are trying to spare them, is to alert your university’s registrar to the potential error. The registrar would be in a better position to check whether this is in fact a clerical error or something that is in accordance with the student’s wishes. And the student would probably perceive an email from an anonymous registrar staff member discussing the option of correcting an incorrect entry in their university records as a lot less creepy than a similar email coming from their professor.

**Edit:** *see also the comment by @niemiro, who said that “The registrar could send an email containing every field in the database for that student and ask for confirmation that it’s all still correct”. If/when you email the registrar, you can suggest to them this approach to minimize any creepiness factor and avoid a risk of accidentally outing the student.*

Other than this idea, doing nothing is a viable, and, in my opinion, completely satisfactory approach to handling a “problem” that you neither know with certainty is actually a problem, nor falls anywhere near your actual professional duties with respect to the student in question.

Comment: I don't think I must do something,just that doing something might be the decent thing to do. If I were a trans student, I think I wouldn't want something very private about me to be shown to every single teacher. I would want to know this was happening so that I could put an end to it.

Comment: The student not knowing is by far the least likely scenario. Much more likely that he’s not out to his parents or that your school, state, or country has trans-unfriendly policies.

Comment: @TooTea understood. Well, it’s reasonable to do something, and it’s reasonable to do nothing. I’ve given a suggestion for what to do if you want to choose the “do something” path.

Comment: If this is indeed a clerical error, contacting the registrar directly would also alert them that they need to double-check the *rest* of the information for this student as well.  Some student profile data (grant/funding information, emergency contacts, etc) could be disastrous if incorrect. Stuff like that doesn't always get audited unless someone lets them know there might be a problem.

Comment: If the student prefers the current situation, then the registrar will probably also be aware of this case.  In that case they may not even bother the student, but this question would be "taken care of" in OP's mind.

Comment: This. The registrar could send an email containing every field in the database for that student and ask for confirmation that it's all still correct and up to date.

Comment: Do not do this. You risk outing the student in the case that employers and/or family have access to their records.

Comment: @LShaver which records? Outing how exactly? I’m confused about what sort of scenario you’re imagining exactly.

Comment: For example, their parents might read their official email. Or maybe some letters are mailed to the students permanent address with a gendered title. Or the parents just open any letters sent to the student at their permanent address. Or maybe gender is mentioned somewhere on financial aid information. Lots of ways this can go horribly wrong.

Comment: @NoahSnyder while I personally think doing nothing is the best option, your objections don’t make sense. The “official email”, if such an email is ever sent, will be an email from the registrar asking the student to confirm that the details of their profile are correct. And if the student is worried about the gender being mentioned in official communications, all they need to do is not change their “parent-safe” gender in the university profile. The student will remain 100% in control. I still don’t see how the action I’m suggesting can lead to outing.

Comment: @NoahSnyder: The question now says the student's photo is "of a bearded dude".  Maybe I'm incorrect here, but that seems unlikely to be someone who maintains a female appearance when seeing their parents.  Without that info, yeah I agree there's more concern that the student isn't out to everyone yet.

Comment: I don't understand how passing the buck to the registrar solves this problem or even addresses the spirit of the OP's question. Suppose the registrar notices the potentially erroneous gender—then what should the *registrar* do? (And I second @LShaver's concern about potentially outing the student to family or others.)

Comment: @Max I believe these concerns are addressed in my answer and the long discussion in the comments. I don’t have anything to add beyond that.

Answer (score 42):

> an undergrad student in a course I teach

Your job is teaching this student.  The gender in the university records has no relevance to that job that I can think of.  Don't do anything unless the student asks you for help with the record.

> wrong gender would keep being shown to dozens of other teachers for years to come

That's true, but I do not see what is has to do with your responsibilities to the student.  Sensible faculty know that student records are full of errors, and quite frequently lack student's preferred names, such as Andy instead of Andrew.

> Is there a better course of action?

If you want to address students by their correct pronoun, invite *all* of them to identify their pronoun at the start of the course.

Comment: The student uses male pronouns,so at least in that regard I'm safe. And FWIW this is the first case of an error in student records I have seen. They really have to be correct as the data is used directly to issue diplomas,grant scholarships and so on.

Comment: If the gender was not relevant it would not have been displayed in the report the teacher sees.

Comment: @WoJ In my experience student records displayed to the instructor have loads of irrelevant information.

Comment: @WoJ Please elaborate on what relevance does it has? Presumably the OP isn't in charge of arranging housing, university students are typically capable of choosing which restroom to use on their own, and pronouns are best established by just asking... So what are you actually doing differently based on M or F?

Comment: @user3067860: I have no idea, I am not American. This does not make any sense in Europe and this kind of information never appears on any report. The US being the US it may make sense there and since it is explicitly mentioned I assume it is there for something.

Comment: @WoJ Sorry,when did the US enter the picture? My original question is about the EU (and tagged as such).

Comment: As an American, I find the "it does not make sense, therefore it must be American" syllogism rather amusing.

Comment: @TooTea: ah, that's a game-changer then :) Which country if I may ask?

Comment: @Kevin: no - this is not that. From all I read (and having worked 15 years for a US company)  the US is much more, say, aware of race, sex, etc. Problems that do not appear in Europe (or at least in France) do pop up in the US. There is nothing derogatory in my sentence.

Comment: @WoJ I work in Czechia and the Netherlands. I'd prefer not to be more specific because this question is now on the HNQ and I don't want to risk deanonymising the student.

Comment: @TooTea: I understand, thanks. In that case, things have changed a lot in the last ~25 years since I left academia. Now that I counted and  wrote it I feel old and not that surprised anymore that things changed. Thanks for the question anyway!

Comment: @WoJ Possibly the list was typed by hand 25 years ago? These days the list is digital and generated using off the shelf software that is sold to thousands of different schools for all ages...and, most importantly, purchasing decisions are made by some administrator who doesn't actually have to use it and probably tries to make sense of competing software packages by comparing nonsense statistics like "number of fields shown".

Comment: Assuming that a student's gender identity is irrelevant to the course, AND that the professor has no particular authority or skill for correcting the database, then doing nothing is the best course of action.

Answer (score 15):

By the use of the word "corrected" you are making an assumption. If they haven't made any declaration then don't *act on* such assumptions.

You could just leave it alone, and if the student wants it changed they will probably act on it. But at most, tell them that they should (might want to) review their student records with the appropriate office to decide on any desired changes.

I'd guess there are students of university age struggling with who they are. To some extend we all experienced that, perhaps.

Comment: Right, "corrected" is probably a mistake (although it would be okay if it is a clerical error, which I think is the much more likely explanation). Perhaps "changed" or something would be better? The whole reason I'm even considering doing something about this is that the web form with these basic personal data is quite well hidden from the perspective of a student (it's filled in once by the administration when enroll in the university and then probably never touched again), but the data from there is shown to every teacher as a part of the list of students enrolled into a course.

Comment: I'm with @buffy here. You make the assumption that something needs to be changed or corrected. That may be true, but it may also not. The student may very well like to keep an ambiguity about their gender, and it's not your job to point out that the record does not reflect how they present *today*. I've known a person who showed up as a woman one day at a conference, and as a man the next.

Answer (score 9):

Sometime every year, the central admin at my university asks me (faculty) to check the correctness of the various bits of "information" they have for me. Sure, address, phone, next-of-kin (in case of accident?), and mostly mundane-though-personal things. This also includes expressions of preference about whether bits of info will be publicly accessible, or not. In the past, the default seemed to have been that lots of stuff was public, but not so much now.

Assuming that students have the same option to adjust/update their "personal information", you should just give a blanket encouragement to students... for gender-related but many more... reasons, to be sure to look at the univ's "personal info + preferences" file for them, and update as needed.

I think this approach would avoid a lot of the invasiveness and potential insensitivity/presumption about dealing directly with the specific possible issue-at-hand.

Comment: This approach feels like a good start, but I feel are 2 things missing: 1) tell the students where to find the information that is held on them, we have had lots of questions here that amount to students not being good at finding information in university computer systems. 2) Explicitly say that gender is self determined and need not match their passport/id card/whatever. Lots of organisations are pedantic about that, so students may not realise they have a choice.

Answer (score 5):

The intent is good.

I would find a way to do it that’s less likely to be professionally dubious and to the student, alarming/creepy/distressing, though.  Which is the likely outcome, handled that way.

> I have noticed that an undergrad student in a course I teach...

This is the key, and it’s **all** that is needed.

If you teach in person, then good, ask them to hold back a moment after a class or supervision session. If not, consider if it’s better to email or ask if you can have a word (adding also "it’s nothing bad, a course admin thing I need to check").

Then simply say something like this:

> Hi! It’s nothing big. I wanted to double check what pronouns you want me to use when we talk *[or work/during supervisions/whatever, pick one as appropriate]*. It matters to get them right and I’d like to be sure rather than make a mistake.

That way you’re using a legitimate reason, that they are your student and you will at some time have to communicate to them, or with them, or about them, to **someone** or other, be it written course correspondence, exams, informal, educational Q&A, discussions with other staff, whatever. So you want to double check what's right, to not make a hurtful thoughtless mistake.

That’s legitimate. It comes over well. And it doesn’t sound like you trawled records. They’ll probably like and appreciate the care involved, which indeed you show.

If you feel this could be an issue affecting others, it’s also not a bad thing to ask all your students at some convenient time, and let them know its okay to advise of pronouns if they wish. Treat it like any admin thing, as routine as letting them know next class time or handing out coursework.

> Hi!  Before we start, I have a small administrative thing. I'm updating my records, and I like to check along with names, if anyone has pronouns that they want to let me know. For reference, mine are [whatever]. If anyone wants to make sure my records are correct, please catch me some time or drop me an email. And now, back to (subject).

The people, to whom it matters, will very much notice the invitation.

Comment: "What pronouns do you want me to use?" and "what should I have in my own records?" are not the same question as "do you want the university's official records changed?"

Comment: The difference is, they are legitimate and valid questions that don't cause issues, **and tell you whether the official records have a problem in the first place**.  Which is what the OP actually wants to know, a non creepy "better course of action". ......

Comment: ...The answer obtained either confirms the official records are right, or allow the OP to legitimately follow up **internally by correcting them without distressing or involving the student further**: _"Hi, I noticed that X appears to be incorrectly listed as female on our official records but he's just confirmed he's male. It came to light as I was checking my own records. Can we correct this? Thanks!"_  Additional benefit, its fixed without emotional labour on the part of the student, rather than demanding they jump extra hoops

Comment: Or, if so desired, by asking them, "okay, I've noted that on mine. Do you want me to chdck/make sure the official university records say the same?

Comment: "Follow up internally without involving the student further" is a very bad idea, when the student hasn't actually indicated that they want OP to do this. As discussed in my answer, it's not safe to assume that changing the record is the student's desired course of action. It's also very unlikely that university admin would be willing to change a student's recorded details just on the say-so of a teacher, without documentation or a direct request from that student.

Comment: Yes, check. For sureBut it solve the OPs actual problem which is identifying if there's actually an issue related to recorded gender vs desired use-gender, without creeping out the student.

Answer (score 5):

I suspect that what has happened here is that your student doesn't realise that their registered gender need not match their passport/ID card/birth certificate. So when they filled out the form, they put down the gender they thought they were obliged to use, even though actually they could have picked the right option.

There is also a non-zero chance that some years ago, when they filled out the form, they weren't sure, but now they are more settled. Statistically, an undergraduate is right in the age band where that can happen, and testosterone acts very fast. It might only take a year to acquire a good beard.

Either way, I agree with the answers that suggest a blanket email rather than targeting this student. Is there an LGBT organisation at the university? Maybe you could ask them to send an email around explaining that;

- The university welcomes folks of all gender, and respects the gender that students self-id as.
- Any student is welcome to change their gender marker in the university database. It need not match any other documents.
- That can be done by going to `https://.....` and clicking on `blah`

If your student is actually trans it's reasonably likely they open an email with something like "encouraging gender self-id" in the header. Of course, it may be that they don't read their email much at all, but we must live in hope.

Answer (score 3):

> I was thinking about sending them a short e-mail along the lines of:
>
> > Dear Student, I have noticed the university records show your gender as female. Should you want to have that corrected, contact the
> > Department of Student Affairs. Feel free to ignore this message if it
> > is not relevant, I don't expect a reply.

This is a good approach, but I might tweak the wording a little, e.g.:

> ...You may already be aware of this, but if not, Student Affairs would be the department to talk to about updating that information.

You're right to take this to the student first and only. Never ever out somebody as trans or maybe-trans without their consent. Let Andy decide whether to take this further.

For a variety of reasons, it's possible that Andy is aware of the record and either doesn't want to change it, or isn't able to change it. Sometimes it's hard, expensive, or even impossible for trans people to get gender markers changed on official docs (e.g. the university requires amended birth certificate, but issuing state refuses to amend).

There can be safety considerations here — Andy might not feel comfortable having such a request on record, or might not want his parents seeing letters addressed to "Mr. Andy Smith".

There can also be administrative reasons, e.g. I know of trans men who've had insurance claims for health services denied because the insurer had a hardcoded rule saying that men couldn't have pap tests.

So, by all means let the student know what's on the record, but don't assume they haven't considered changing it.

Comment: I know a person whose father was completely drunk when he arrived at the registry office to record her birth. She didn't get the name that her mum and dad agreed on as a result. She's lucky she was registered as female, that was probably a 50/50 chance.

Comment: @gnasher729 I recall at least one case where an immigration official misspelled the family's name and it was easier for the entire family just to change to the misspelling than to get it fixed.

Answer (score 3):

99% of students see themselves as either male or female. Among bearded blokes named Andy the percentage may be higher.

A simple question to the person: “Hi, according to the student database you are female. Is that correct?” will give the student an opportunity to either tell you it’s correct, or to fix a mistake. And there’s the possibility that the wrong picture ended up on the database.

And please nothing like “should you want that corrected” - here you are making assumptions. A simple question makes no assumptions. If I was Andy and you said I was a “potentially trans student”, I’d be very annoyed about you making assumptions. PS. I know a lady whose complete name is the same as mine except for one letter. Had we been at the same university, any mixups wouldn’t have been too surprising.

Comment: No way this is a wrong picture. We meet in person every week and the student looks very much like the one in the photo. But isn't directly asking about their gender (which is absolutely none of my business) way worse than just pointing out what I see and letting them decide whether to do anything?

Comment: You wouldn't ask about the gender. You would ask "is there an error in the student records"? And excuse me, but for most people you get their gender correctly, and for a large portion of the rest you got the gender that they want you to assume.

Comment: I very much agree with @gnasher729 here. Don't assume anything, that's non of your bussiness. Nothing here is strictly your responsibility, the only thing you can claim is a general interest in the admin being correct as a member of the institution. So they most you can do is ask 'Is this correct?' and accept whatever answer you get. It's also the best thing to do because it allows the student to just say 'Yes' and walk away (as is their right).

Answer (score -2):

Very hidden [in the comments](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/182978/potentially-trans-student-misgendered-in-university-records-what-to-do?noredirect=1#comment491620_182978) to the question, the OP states

> "the student uses male pronouns."

There you go. You absolutely do not need any other information, and if you feel the urge of taking actions, simply write to the maintainer of the database or to the relevant office and point out there is a typo in that database field, but as other already pointed out, it is best to leave that to the student themselves.

Comment: No investigations, no typical male physical attributes, no creepy direct question to the student, really noting else is needed.

Comment: Sorry, but this isn't going to work. The standard procedure is for students themselves to request any changes to their personal data, and it would be extremely awkward for me to request changes to somebody else's record. It will have to involve the student and the whole point of my question is how to do that.

Comment: Actually, whatever pronouns you use, and what gender you identify as, do not need to be linked. So you can't just draw conclusions just like that.

Comment: @IvoBeckers very good point. How offensive would you find a direct question "what gender do you identify with?", from a peer and from a person superior to me in the power-scale? I, and I speak for myself, respectively "a bit offensive" and "very offensive".

Comment: @EarlGrey for me personally I wouldn't care, but I can imagine a large percentage would find it offensive yeah. I also do not claim to know the best course of action here, I merely wanted to make that remark

Comment: @IvoBeckers I totally agree, but in the academia english speaking world, it is common to self express how to be addressed (his/her/their) and it is assumed that such expression clarify the gender (especially with his/her). 
Your remark "whatever pronouns you use, and what gender you identify as, do not need to be linked" was true until some years ago, nowadays less and less.

Answer (score -3):

You are seeing the tip of a tree, but there is a forest that you need to burn down as fast as possible: **why are students' genders recorded?**

The student can take care of themselves. Maybe it has already been done, and maybe they will be a female in three months, who knows. Maybe they already are, and this is none of your business.

You can start a movement to ban the recording of gender in students' registers.

Comment: Quite frankly, this is not a hill I'm willing to die on. As you might have noticed I know very little about the issues of gender and the like. I'd love to be able to help one particular student out, but I'm certainly not going to start a big movement to have half of the university systems and processes overhauled.

Comment: @EarlGrey Since you asked for feedback, I downvoted because your answer, while correct, does not address the question.  The asker, as an instructor, cannot change the fact that gender is recorded.

Comment: @TooTea "I'm certainly not going to start a big movement to have half of the university systems and processes overhauled." I am sure you have good intentions, but instead of fixing a potentially dangerous system, you give the burden to the potential victims of "saving" themselves from the dangerous system, while you absolutely have the power to move and change something, since you are in the system.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this (quite interesting) conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134586/discussion-on-answer-by-earlgrey-potentially-trans-student-misgendered-in-univer). Please use the chat for continued discussion; comments below this one should have a realistic chance of leading to the answer being edited.

Comment: Re *"the tip of a tree"*: Do you mean *"the [tip of the iceberg](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tip_of_the_iceberg#Noun)"*?

Comment: They [burn down the forests on other planets](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fMoPR2IA2Uk&t=2m11s), but here? Is it the idiom *[see the forest for the trees](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/see_the_forest_for_the_trees#Verb)* that is referred to?

Comment: This is a non-starter, because recording data on gender and other protected categories is all but essential for a university that wants to assure its compliance with anti-discrimination laws. For instance, without that data it's much harder to tell whether your recruitment process is unduly favouring one gender over another.

Comment: @PeterMortensen thanks.

Comment: @GeoffreyBrent and is it necessary to share these informations with teachers&co?

Comment: @EarlGrey Often a person's gender isn't obvious from their physical appearance, and providing that information - assuming it's correct! - can avoid some awkward "sir-er-ma'am-er-sir" moments.

Comment: @GeoffreyBrent this goes against whatever small steps against gender discrimination we did in the past few years. Gender is not important, can we get rid of archaic way of expressing ourselves? We are in academia:SE, most of the discussion is about research&progress, but we still use wordings from centuries/millenia ago :) ! Why can't you simply say "dear student"instead of "dear sir/ma'am"? I admit in English is super easy, less so in other languages ...

Comment: dear @PeterMortensen I am sorry you could not find a correct codification for that expression, but hey, if John Heywood documented the English use of the proverb in 1546, why can't Peter Mortensen document the international use of such an expression in 2022? 
Do as many edits as you want, but ask yourself: am I crystallizing the language?